# Use variables from another class

Tags: python, class, variables

How do you access a variable of one class from another?

Below is the code I'm working with and I need to be able to use `thing1` and `thing2` variables from the `MainHandler` (since you can only access "request" from that class).

I need this variable so that I can use the string that it returns below in the html.

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        p = Page()

        if self.request.GET:
            thing1 = self.request.GET['thing1']
            thing2 = self.request.GET['thing2']
            self.response.write(p.print_final())
            print thing1 + thing2
        else:
            self.response.write(p.print_this())
class Page(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stuff = """
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Give Us Yo INFO</title>
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>Some Header</h1>
        </header>

        <div class="main-form">
            <form method="GET" action="">
                <h2>Your Juice Sheet</h2>

                <label>Name: </label>
                <input type="text" name="thing1">

                <label>Email: </label>
                <input type="text" name="thing2">

                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
        """
        self.final = """
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Give us YO INFO</title>
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>Some Header</h1>
        </header>

        <div class="result">
            <h2>Thing1</h2>
            <div class= "thing1-input">
                <h3>Name</h3>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class= "thing2-input">
                <h3>Thing2</h3>
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
        """
    def print_this(self):
        page_content = self.stuff
        page_content = page_content.format(**locals())
        return page_content
    def print_final(self):
        final_page_content = self.final
        final_page_content = final_page_content.format(**locals())
        return final_page_content


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Comment: By the way, it would be better if you edit-in your _relevant code_ to question instead of linking your code.

Comment: @Lafexlos My assumption is that this is an issue that an experienced python developer would be able to point out quite quickly. Also, I wasn't too sure how to display it openly here. I thought it was 4 spaces but I guess I was wrong.

Comment: Just for future reference about formatting. [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) or [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `thing1` and `thing2` is local to the `get` method of the `MainHandler` class.

In other words, these values are not visible outside of the `get` method, so there is no real way to "get to them" right now.

However, since you are calling the `print_final` and `print_this` methods from `get`, you can pass the value of `thing1` and `thing2` to them, like this:

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        p = Page()

        if self.request.GET:
            thing1 = self.request.GET['thing1']
            thing2 = self.request.GET['thing2']

            self.response.write(p.print_final(thing1, thing2))
            # --------------------------------^^^^^^  ^^^^^^
            print thing1 + thing2
        else:
            self.response.write(p.print_this())
```

Then, modify the `print_final` method to accept these two extra arguments:

```
def print_final(self, thing1, thing2):
    final_page_content = self.final
    final_page_content = final_page_content.format(**locals())
    return final_page_content
```

Comment: I think that this may work but now how would I inject those values into the html so that the entered data shows on the final page?

Comment: Never mind, figured it out myself. You sir, are exemplary!

Answer (score 0):

On `Page` creation, pass reference of `MainHandler`. And make `thing1` and `thing2` an object variable (not just local).

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        p = Page(self)

        if self.request.GET:
            self.thing1 = self.request.GET['thing1']
            self.thing2 = self.request.GET['thing2']
            self.response.write(p.print_final())
            print self.thing1 + self.thing2
        ...

class Page(object):
    def __init__(self, handler):
        self.handler = handler
        # you can now use self.handler.thing1
        self.stuff = ...
```

Comment: actually, I tried that and it didn't work. Caused me a headache for about 2 hours before coming here. Did you receive a different result?